# Mapa Leaflet - Acessar extends

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives, maps

Olá, estou utilizando a diretiva "Angular Leaflet Directive" (http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/) junto ao Leaflet map.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, existe a possibilidade de inserir alguma variável ou scope nesse extend?

```
    angular.extend(vm, { // ESTENDE AS PROPRIEDADES DO MAP (MARCADORES, LOCALIZAÇÃO INCIAL..)
        center: { // LOCALIZAÇÃO INICIAL  .
            lat:  -15.25241,
            lng: -52.21115241,
            zoom: 4
        },
        markers: vm.markers,
        defaults: {
            tileLayer: "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            tileLayerOptions: {
                detectRetina: true,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> | &copy <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">Funil PRÓ</a>'
            },
        }
    });
```

O que eu preciso fazer é alterar as coordenadas conforme o click em um elemento na view e quando insiro uma variável "externa" neste componente ele simplesmente para de funcionar. Agradeço desde já!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo fazer o que queria. Tenho uma tabela com o nome das cidades e quando o usuário clica na cidade, altera as coordenadas do mapa para a cidade selecionada.

Esta é minha função do click:

```
    vm.converterCidadeEstado = function(cidade) {
        vm.cidadeEstado = cidade.cidade + ', ' + cidade.estado;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ "address": vm.cidadeEstado }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
                var localizacao = results[0].geometry.location,
                    lat = localizacao.lat(),
                    lng = localizacao.lng();
                vm.latitudeCidadeUf = lat;
                vm.longitudeCidadeUf = lng;
                $timeout(function() {
                    vm.center = {
                        lat: vm.latitudeCidadeUf,
                        lng: vm.longitudeCidadeUf,
                        zoom: 11
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

A função recebe os valores de cidade e estado, converte para lat e lng, após isso altera a latitude e longitude do map.

Answer (score 2):

Pergunta - existe alguma razão específica pela qual você está utilizando `angular.extend()`?

Você pode implementar uma solução simplesmente utilizando objetos simples - propriedades de escopo, por exemplo.

O exemplo funcional abaixo demonstra a adição dinâmica de um novo marcador ao mapa. Clique em <kbd>Executar</kbd> para vê-lo em ação.

```js
var app = angular.module('demoapp',['leaflet-directive']);

app.controller('DemoController', function($scope, leafletData) {

  $scope.config = { // Contém toda a configuração para a diretiva [leaflet].
    center : {
      lat:  -15.25241,
      lng: -52.21115241,
      zoom: 4
    },
    markers: [], // coleção de marcadores.
    defaults: {
      tileLayer: "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      tileLayerOptions: {
        detectRetina: true,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> | &copy <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">Funil PRÓ</a>'
      },
    }
  };

  $scope.addMarker = function(){
    var marker =  { // define um novo marcador...
      lat:  -15.25241 + ( Math.random() * 10 -5 ),
      lng: -52.21115241 + ( Math.random() * 10 -5 ),
      message: "Marcador adicionado!",
      focus: true,
      draggable: false
    } 
    $scope.config.markers.push(marker); // ...e o adiciona ao mapa
  }




});
```

```css
.angular-leaflet-map {
    width: 640px;
    height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<body ng-app='demoapp'>
  <div ng-controller="DemoController" ng-click="addMarker()">
    <button>Adicionar marcador</button>
    
    <leaflet markers="config.markers" center="config.center"></leaflet>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Olá! Então, estava utilizando o `angular.extend` porque em todos os exemplos que encontrei também utilizavam, como funcionou não mudei isso hehe. 

Vou editar minha pergunta e postar o código todo do mapa, pra ficar menos confuso.